# Problem relating to presentmodelViewController

Tags: iphone

IN my apllication i have three Views One,Two,Three.

In all view I made one single button with respective action.

flow of my program :-

1) first my One View will load on that i have one button with action

-(IBAction)two:(id)sender
{
Mydelegate *ptr_Two = (Mydelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
[self presentmodelViewController:ptr_Two.LinkOfTwo animated:YES];

}

2) In the above way when I click on button  then my Second view Will appear.

3) In second screen my Third screen will appear on click of button

Now i have one more button in all screen for
[self dismissModelViewController animated:YES];

My problem is that when i click the button of third screen my second screen will appear but at the same time i want my second screen will automatically dissmiss and first will come appear.

I mean I want to switch directly to first screen by calling void function of second screen for dismissModelviewController

how it could be possible

Please tell me its urgent

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you'd like to be able to switch from the third to the first screen, with just one action by the user? In that case, make all but one of your dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: calls with a NO parameter. If you try to dismiss multiple modal viewControllers, all animated, all at the same time, you'll crash.